# Is there a way to switch characters in offline practice?

Tags: alien-swarm

How can I switch characters in offline practice in Alien Swarm?  That is I want to practice as the special weapons or tech character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than choosing which character you want to play in the lobby screen, you can also change which character you control during the mission itself, by using the F keys; <kbd>F1</kbd> will let you control the first character (the one you started the mission with), <kbd>F2</kbd> will let you control the 2nd, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `F1`, `F2`, `F3` or `F4` to take over *bots* at any time. This is not limited to offline practice; although I don't know how you can get drones in your team, I know it is possible.

Comment: For now, it happens only if you are the leader, and someone from your team leaves after the missions starts. It's not yet possible to add them yourself, unfortunately.

Comment: @Gnoupi
http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3355/how-can-i-add-bots-to-an-alien-swarm-online-game

Comment: I know, I also commented there :)

Comment: *Drones* are the most common aliens, not *bots*! It was so funny to read this. You can't actually get aliens in your team...

Comment: @Blax Fixed! No +2 for you though :P