# How can I add bots to an Alien Swarm online game?

Tags: alien-swarm

How can I play Alien Swarm with only one friend and have the AI control the other two characters?

I find it very difficult to play with only 2 characters, and I'd like to fill the empty slots with AI.

I know it must be possible somehow.

**EDIT**: [The accepted answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3355/how-can-i-add-bots-to-an-alien-swarm-online-game/3363#3363) works, but the bots don't do anything more than firing (no healing, no welding, nothing). I have to control them to do anything more than just firing.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: I've been doing Alien Swarm with one friend -- just [he](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198005660458/stats/AlienSwarm) (low level techie: prototype, ammo and welder) and [me](http://steamcommunity.com/id/badp/stats/AlienSwarm) (mid level medic: flamethrower, healgun and armor). Very doable and fun on easy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To add a bot to your game: `cl_selectm (marinenum) (slot)`

To remove a bot from your game: `cl_dselectm (marinenum)`

(marinenum) should be between 0-7 and corresponds to the character to be added.

(slot) should be between 0-3 and relates to the player slot the bot will fill. -1 can also be used; this will fill the next available slot.

These commands must be used while in the lobby; using them anywhere else will result in invalid command errors.

[Source/More information](http://forums.blackcatgames.com/showthread.php?t=12996)

Comment: Great! Do you know what happens if a friend connects while the game is in progress? Will he be able to control one of the AI bots?

Comment: Yes, [these buttons still work](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3350/is-there-a-way-to-switch-characters-in-offline-practice).

Comment: @Juan Manuel
It's hard for me to be certain given the game's immaturity, but I don't think it's possible to resolve your issue. Given that the game is open source, somebody may see fit to augment the default AI. If it's important to you, perhaps you could search for an emergent Alien Swarm developer community and ask there.

Comment: I didn't know this till I tried to access the console - it's disabled by default. To enable the console, go to the options list and select Keyboard / Mouse controls. Near the bottom of that screen is a checkbox to enable 'Developer console'. Following this, press "`" to access the console (on UK English keyboards, this is the top left button)

Answer (score 1):

This is a response to:

> EDIT: The accepted answer works, but the bots don't do anything more than firing (no healing, no welding, nothing). I have to control them to do anything more than just firing.
>
> Does anybody know how to solve this?

The lobby leader commands the bots. You can see this by looking on your minimap (the red lines between the leader and the bots). You have to give them a "GO" sign for them to start moving. Or a "STOP" sign for them to hold position. Other needed commands should be given by pressing the action key (E) on hackable terminals and invertory keys 1, 2, 3, and 4 for bots to do something associated with their invertory (for example to command the medic to place the healing beacon, to weld ...). Some extra options for offhand items might show up while holding the crouch key (Shift by default). To use them, press the corresponding invertory key (1, 2, 3 or 4) while holding Shift.

So for them to follow you, you should press the **V** key on your keyboard to give them the move command (by default).